# How Can I Get These Lights to flash up in Sequence?

Tags: javascript, sequence

This is my first time coding - I did some learning on Codecademy, but have hit a bit of a wall of what I am trying to do next for a task...

I want to have my colours in this grid flash up individually and in order, but I don't know how to go about it! This is what I have so far, but don't know where I go next - I've been pulling my hair out over how to fix it for the past 5 hours after trying so many different variations XD

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpotey/kaz3uvzr/4/)**

```js
var colouredboxes = {
  yellowbox: [
    'yellow'
  ],
  greenbox: [
    'green'
  ],
  bluebox: [
    'blue'
  ],
  whitebox: [
    'white'
  ],
  orangebox: [
    'orange'
  ]
};
```

Comment: can you show more code? how are you trying to 'light' the boxes?

Comment: Oh sorry - does the jsfiddle link not work? :S - yeah, I'm trying to get 5 boxes to flash up individually in certain colours before repeating the sequence. Sorry new to all this sort of stuff!

Comment: Jepp the link is working....

But everything inside is not even close to it.
The script inside is not even trying to touch the elements ;)

Comment: Working on an Answer, here is Fiddle, which is not working the way you want it, but at least doing anything ;)   https://jsfiddle.net/kaz3uvzr/13/

Comment: In what order would you like them to flash? IN the order which is in your array or in the order its marked in the markup?

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! The order in the array if you could please!

Comment: Well, you are actually not using an array but an object having arrays as properties. That is a little weird, but somehow things are working now, see answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I won't write your code for you, but I'll give you some steps.

First of all, when you want to go over the boxes in order, you need numbers. `colouredboxes` is an Object with strings as `keys`, and looping over an object is possible, but the order cannot be guaranteed.
So instead, use an array, like this:

```
var colouredboxes = new Array(
        {'yellowbox','yellow'},
        {'greenbox','green'}
        {'bluebox','blue'},
        {'whitebox','white'},
        {'orangebox','orange'}
    );
```

- Now you can a `for(i=0;i<6;i++){..}` loop over the Array.
- Inside that loop, you can access the elements:

the `id`: is `colouredboxes[x][0]`

the `color`: is `colouredboxes[x][1]`

- With the id, you can get the box:

`var box = document.getElementById(colouredboxes[x][0])`;

- And when you have the box, you can set it's color:

  `box.style.backgroundColor=colouredboxes[x][1];`

Comment: Thank you so much for the pointers! So something a bit like this for the array instead?    `var colouredboxes = new Array(
colouredboxes[0] = 'square2id', 'yellow',
colouredboxes[1] = 'square4id', 'green',
colouredboxes[2] = 'square3id', 'blue',
colouredboxes[3] = 'square1id', 'white',
colouredboxes[4] = 'square5id', 'orange');`

Comment: This will definitely not work. You have to pair the number and id/color as a `key/value` pair. `{'redbox','red'}`. Now you have some items with a key, and others don't. And as you are defining the Array, this `colouredboxes[0] = 'square2id'` will not work.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help! Michel - can you explain to me why 'var maxbox = colouredboxes.length - 1;' why do you need the '- 1'?

Comment: The length of an array is the amount of elements in it. `Array (a,b,c)` has a length of 3. But all Arrays start at key 0, so when you loop over it by keys, you have to go from 0 till length-1. Lets say length=5 (so the array keys are 0 till 4). I could have done `if(i==5) i=0` but this only is true when `i = 5`. I like to work on the safe side. With `if(i>5-1)` I catch every `i` equal to or greater than 5. In this case there can't go much wrong, but in more complex code it is better to be safe then sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working, here is the fiddle...

https://jsfiddle.net/kaz3uvzr/14/

For your explanation:

```js
var colouredboxes = { yellowbox: [ 'yellow'], greenbox: [ 'green'], bluebox: [ 'blue'], whitebox: [ 'white'], orangebox: [ 'orange'] };
counter = 0.1;

for (x in colouredboxes){   
     setColorSwitch(x, counter);
    counter ++;
}
console.log(Object.keys(colouredboxes).length);
function setColorSwitch(id,timing){
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById(id).style.background = colouredboxes[id][0];
        setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById(id).style.background = "black";
                              setColorSwitch(id, Object.keys(colouredboxes).length-1);}
        ,1000)}
    ,1000 * timing); 
}
```

```css
.container {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:860px;
}
.box {
    width:210px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#151A24;
    margin-bottom:3px;
}
.spacing {
    margin-right:3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div id="whitebox" class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div id="yellowbox" class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div id="bluebox" class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div id="greenbox" class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div id="orangebox" class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

So, as you can see in the snippet, i added a few lines of code to your JS section.

First thing is i got through every property, you have in your Object(colouredboxes).
Inside that loop i call the function setColorSwitch. I defined it later.

```
for (x in colouredboxes){   
         setColorSwitch(x, counter);
        counter ++;
    }
```

The counter which i am counting up, is used for the delay in changing the color of each box and is only used once per box.

next thing i do is change the backgroundcolor of the Object to the Value, you have in your property.

```
document.getElementById(id).style.background = colouredboxes[id][0];
```

Then i again have a set timeout routine, set to 1 second, making the box go back to black and call the function again with the same id and a delay of: numbersofproperties -1 (Seems to be the most fluent solution).

```
document.getElementById(id).style.background = "black";
setColorSwitch(id, Object.keys(colouredboxes).length-1);},1000)
```

Thats it.